# How to generate two separate Maven CheckStyle HTML reports?

Tags: maven, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

I'd like to to generate two separate Maven HTML CheckStyle reports with different configurations:

- the first one checks the main classes (`src/main/java/**`) with configuration #1 (`<configLocation>`)
- the second one checks the test classes (`src/test/java/`) with configuration #2 (`<configLocation>`) which is somewhat relaxed regarding of configuration #1

I played a lot with multiple `executions`, `configurations`, and `reportSets`, etc. but I've never been able to make it work. The generated report only take into account the last execution of the plugin. I'm now wondering if it's even possible...

**Edited:**

Added **HTML** report.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `outputFile` property in your config to set different file for report. And create 2 executions for main code and test code with different output files.
For example, config below will generate result report in file `your_file.xml` in base directory of your project.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${checkstyle.plugin.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <outputFile>${project.basedir}/your_file.xml</outputFile>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Full description of property is [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/checkstyle-mojo.html#outputFile)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I forgot to specify that I'd like an HTML report. Sorry about that. I edited my question.